# Splitting a single fiber connection with multiple public IPs to two separate routers

Tags: networking, ip-routing

We have a single WAN connection coming into our office and have 5 public IP addresses from our ISP. We have 2 separate entities underneath our main company and I want to be able to completely split them out into two separate physical networks.

Ideally I'd like to figure out how to have a topology where the ISP WAN comes into a switch or other device and then splits the connection to two separate routers. I'd like the WAN ports of the routers to each be assigned one of the unique public IP addresses and not a private IP address.

My goal is to manage entity A myself and let entity B manage routing, DHCP, VLANS, etc themselves without interaction from me.

Would a simple 1GB switch between the ISP connection and the 2 separate routers satisfy this?

Comment: How are the IP addresses setup?  Do you have a /29 subnet, with one of the addresses being their gateway?

Comment: Yes. They provided me a /29 and a gateway IP.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that'll work, as long as your ISP gave you two public IP's that can be used on your routers.